# Rosewill Apollo RK-9100xR driver for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, keyboard

I just bought a Rosewill mechanical keyboard (RK-9100xR) which works perfectly fine in Windows as it has drivers available for the same, but I could not find any drivers for Linux. I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and on it, the keyboard works fine but none of the LEDs toggle (for Num lock et al). Is there a way I can find a driver for it and install it. The Rosewill website has drivers only for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can find a driver for it and install it

No, it looks like there is not even a hint of this keyboard in relation to anything else than Windows.

If not on their website I would advice to mail them and ask for them to supply it (something like "I am very fond of this keyboard but had to return it because I could not get this to work on Ubuntu"). If nobody mails the they never will create one.

---

I would approach this from another angle and advice to have a look at the `xset` command (`xset` is a tool to confige settings and the `led` options toggles leds). If these work:

```
xset  led named "Scroll Lock"
xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
```

you could alter your keyboard layout to execute these commands. `xset` has many more options:

```
led     The  led  option controls the keyboard LEDs.  This controls the
           turning on or off of one or all of the  LEDs.   It  accepts  an
           optional  integer, a preceding dash(-) or an 'on/off' flag.  If
           no parameter or the 'on' flag is given, all LEDs are turned on.
           If  a  preceding  dash or the flag 'off' is given, all LEDs are
           turned off.  If a value between 1 and 32  is  given,  that  LED
           will  be  turned on or off depending on the existence of a pre‐
           ceding dash.  ``xset led 3'' would turn led #3 on.  ``xset -led
           3''  would turn it off.  The particular LED values may refer to
           different LEDs on different hardware.  If the X server supports
           the  XKEYBOARD  (XKB)  extension, leds may be referenced by the
           XKB indicator name by specifying the `named'  keyword  and  the
           indicator name.   For example, to turn on the Scroll Lock LED:

           xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried `xset`. It did not work though.